# How to return queryset using AJAX in django?

Tags: django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

Here is my **view.py** :

```
def get_group_ajax(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        g_id = request.GET['group_id']
        productlist = models.Stocksupporter.objects.filter(pmaingroups = g_id).values('productname').exclude(numberqut=0) *//This is my queryset*
```

Here is my **AJAX** and used **Django template for loop** :

```
$("#allgrp").change(function () {
    const gId = $('#allgrp').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '{% url "webapp:get_group_ajax" %}',
      data: {
        'group_id': gId,
      },
      success: function (data) {
          html_data = 
          `
          {% for pr in productlist %}
          <div class="cardc" id="card_id">
            <p>{{ pr.productname }}</p>
          </div>
          {% endfor %} 
           `;
         
          $("#card_id2").html(html_data);
      }
    });
  });
```

now what is ***problem:***
I want return **productlist** (for loop) in AJAX Success based on selected value (mean group id), i used Response methods but still can not return anything.
is there any way for do it?

Comment: I think you do not understand something ? Your template is rendering one time when you display your page and all django template tags and filter is proceessed at this time. Your ajax call will trigger after this rendering so you can put only javascript code into the success function

Comment: After display your page, right click > source code and you will understand the problem i guess

Comment: @LucasGrugru , which js code is should put in success that can filter list based on selected group id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

views.py :

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

if 'group_id' in request.GET:
    productlist = Stocksupporter.objects.filter(pmaingroups = g_id).exclude(numberqut=0).values('productname')
    return JsonResponse(list(productlist ),safe=False)
```

Success function in html:

```
function(productListData){
   for(i in productListData){
     let element = ` <div class="cardc">
        <p>${productListData[i].productname}</p>
      </div>`
      $("#card_id2").append(element);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. is this put any item in list sperated dives? or put all of list in one div?

Comment: It creates new div for each item.